# attribute value in HTML tag changes after using requests.get and parsing with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

I am trying to scrape Yahoo Finance (https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL), however the attribute value associated with the data point I am trying to get changes. As you can see from picture [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKgE8.jpg), the "span" tag has attribute data-reactid="52". (Highlighted in blue on picture [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKgE8.jpg))

My code to get this data point is the following:

```
home_page = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL"
response = requests.get(home_page)
print(response.status_code)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,'lxml')

header = soup.find("div", attrs = {'id':'quote-header-info'})
company_name = header.find("h1", attrs = {'data-reactid':'7'}).text
price = soup.find("span", attrs = {'span':'data-reactid':'52'})
```

Unfortunately, this returns a value of None. (I have used a different parser (html5lib) but get the same response)

After inspecting the soup, I noticed that the attribute value associated with this data point had changed. See picture [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWMCt.jpg) (It is hard to see, but the tag is slightly highlighted in gray, upper section of the image).

Is there anyway to prevent the values from changing? Or what is a workaround this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the xpath. You can't do it in BS but use lxml.

```
from lxml import html

home_page = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL"
response = requests.get(home_page)
tree = html.fromstring(response.content)
price = str(tree.xpath('//*[@id="quote-header info"]/div[3]/div[1]//span[1]//text()')[0])
```

Selenium would also be great for this. But I hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I was not able to make your code work, were you? I was able to obtain the name of the company using Xpath  (doc.xpath("//h1[@data-reactid = '7']/text()")). The company name, however, I was also able to obtain using BeautifulSoup. It seems that using Xpath and lxml does not fix the problem I described above. I looked into Selenium, I will try this alternative.

Comment: I was able to when I responded so that is odd. Now it's pulling an empty list for me. Another option is this: http://theautomatic.net/yahoo_fin-documentation/ It will pull the same data in way less code.

Comment: Like if you just want to get apple's current price it would be this: from yahoo_fin import stock_info as si
si.get_live_price("aapl")

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the classes that seems stable over time (At least for quite a long time now).

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
print(soup.select_one('.Mb\(-4px\)').text)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this argument works ['.Mb\(-4px\)'] as opposed to writing the whole attribute value ['Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)']. I keep getting the following error: ["SelectorSyntaxError: Invalid character '(' position 5"]. I am assuming the backslashes take care of the problem? (I just do not understand the logic). Also how do you get away from writing the whole attribute value?